# Hole-in-one without touching the ground

Tags: terminology, records, golf

Is there golf terminology for a hole-in-one that doesn't hit the ground and roll into the hole but rather sinks directly into the hole?

I can't really follow what happens in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZT37Bu0kA4&ab_channel=DENNIS199711DENNIS199711) but going by the description it might be an example. I'm guessing this is an exceptionally rare phenomenon. Is there any information about it, like, has there ever been a prize awarded for it? Is there any reason why there isn't more credit/value accorded to it? I mean, I know that you'd need to be not just skilful but astronomically lucky to hit one of these, but same goes for a normal hole-in-one, yet the latter are considered a holy grail of golf.

Answer (score 3):

You might find TV/press calling it a 'slam-dunk' or similar but there is no official description for it. In a parallel universe where that shot goes in but it lands on the green and rolls in I’d wager that the player’s celebration would be no different in that youtube video. An ace by Tiger Woods is described as ‘on the fly’ [here](https://thegolfnewsnet.com/golfnewsnetteam/2020/04/13/how-many-holes-in-one-has-tiger-woods-made-in-his-life-118894/). I cannot find a video of it but would guess that that went straight in the hole as well. [You get both 'slam dunk' and 'on the fly' for this article and video](https://www.sbnation.com/golf/2014/10/26/7074409/will-mackenzie-hole-in-one-mcgladrey-classic-2014) and the player doesn't even know it has gone in!

As a spectacle a ball that goes straight in can be less exciting for the crowd and TV as it is over and done straight away, anyone who lost sight of the ball in the air would probably miss it. The Sunday pin on the 16th at Augusta is in a location that makes holes in one relatively common but the player has to land the ball towards the centre of the green and let the slope bring the ball down towards the hole. Fans know this so when the ball lands in the right area the anticipation builds as it tracks towards the hole. [In this highlight reel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLZ9QSfNsbo&ab_channel=SkySportsGolf) seven of the ten clips are from the 16th hole and only one player hits the ball straight at the hole (no. 5 Charley Hoffman) and judging by his body language and cry of ‘no’ at 2:17 he is not happy with the shot (until it goes in of course). Then [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lzuoTarQjs&ab_channel=TheMasters) is Jon Rahm taking the total opposite approach to a slam-dunk ace on the 16th in a practice round (in sadly crowd-less circumstances).

Unless you are playing in exceptionally soft conditions, a ball that hits the hole direct is actually not quite as a good a shot as one that lands on the green and rolls into the hole. If the ball lands just 3 inches either side of the hole it could run through to the back of the green. A ball striking the flag stick can go anywhere, [as shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1WzFfq0qSM&ab_channel=PGATOUR). I have never had an ace but I have holed full, pitch and chip shots from off the green, the ones that landed straight in the hole have always been mishits. Perversely the better a player is at golf the less likely they are to aim straight at the hole, they are more likely to aim at a landing zone on the green (but maybe not near the hole) which limits the risk of the mishit but maximises their chance of birdie.

Finally, it is custom to buy everyone a drink in the bar after the round if you get a hole in one. A playing partner may have to buy their own drink if they start splitting hairs over how the ball ended up in the bottom of the cup.